# Why Apache RewriteRule treats the same way with '&' and '?'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to code a custom rewrite rule for '.htaccess' file in my Apache webserver.

The main idea is to handle requests in the form:

```
example.com/foo
```

to 'index.php' file in the www_root:

```
example.com/index.php?queryString1=foo
```

As everyone knows, this is easy to do. Just by adding below lines to '.htaccess' file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?queryString1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**But the problem is that** when we want to add another query string to the request, for example as follows:

```
example.com/foo?queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz
```

contrary to my expectations, the following URL does the same:

```
example.com/foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz
```

I don't want the second case (in which second query string starts with '&') to be executed.
Also, if you write in 'index.php' file:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], TRUE).'</pre>'; ?>
```

then, the output of both URLs (`example.com/foo?queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz` and `example.com/foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz`) will be unique:

```
queryString1=foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong with my codes in '.htaccess' file? Thanks.

Comment: In the last case, example.com/foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz, &queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz is not handled as arguments but a big FOO=foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz, $1=foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz

Comment: @jacouh I do not fully understand what you mean, but in general, the URLs are case sensitive.

Comment: I meant that that foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz is taken as a simple url string, not as url arguments.

Comment: @jacouh I do not agree with you on this. If you use the following code, you will have 3 urlStrings: `foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {echo 'Key = ' . $key . '<br />'; echo 'Value= ' . $value . '<br />';}`

Comment: Yes this is the case for you after rewrting, it's just a chance that $1 is appended on index.php?queryString1=$1, as $1=foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz, that's valid arguments arrangement.

Comment: You can prove it by using RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?queryString1=$1 [L] - without QSA, the second case always gives QUERY_STRING queryString1=foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz

Comment: @jacouh Yes you are right. Removing 'QSA' can help. But I need the second queryString in the same form with '?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After above discussion, apache2 does not handle & and ? in the same way. "?" is separator of URL from QUERY_STRING, but & is a normal character as part of URL matched by apache2 RewriteRule.

In pattern of https://www.example.com/URL?QUERY_STRING, URL is only matched by RewriteRule in .htaccess file, it's the string after the hostname and port if given, and before the query string [ref.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), without the leading slash /.

Be careful, in apache2 configuration files vhosts.conf or alike, read when apache2 server starts, RewriteRule mathches against `/URL` string (yes with the leading slash).

The OP's case is just a chance, not general rule. I've tested this for the solution by triggering a `404 Not Found` error if & is involved in URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)$ index.php?queryString1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

`example.com/foo&queryString2=bar&queryString3=baz` will yield a 404 error.

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is better than `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

The character range [^&] means any character but not &. With regex ^([^&]*)$, we select a string containing no & from beginning represented by ^, to the end reprerented by $, so & sign free.

Comment: Wow! It worked. Without any problem. Can you guide me about the regex `^([^&]*)$` in RewriteRule? What is the difference with my code `^(.*)$`? Thanks alot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it in my response.